# GPU underclock itself when full load and overclock itself when empty load

Tags: windows, graphics-card, gpu

Here is a screenshot of GPU-Z, take a look at GPU Core Clock and GPU Load.

[image]

I think this might have something to do with recent windows update, but I checked the update history, there's nothing relates to GPU. I didn't update my GPU driver recently.

Now I can't even watch a video in fullscreen without lag.

My GPU is HD4400, I'm running Win8.1 x64.

**Update:**

My computer some how managed to fix itself today, I didn't do anything, not even a reboot. Now it's always 1100 MHz when plugged in.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill The question is of course how to get rid of this weird behavior.

Comment: I have no idea why I thought you were asking about a Nvidia card.  I don't see any odd behavior.  What driver version are you using?  Intel recently released an update that improves performance.

Comment: @Ramhound It's 10.18.10.3958, I know it's not the latest from intel, but I can't install any driver downloaded from intel, the error message tells me that I have to get it from the computer manufacture. And 3958 is the latest version I can get from Lenovo. I'm using Thinkpad X1 Carbon 2014.

Comment: What processor do you have that reason doesn't make sense every Intel 4000HD+ supports the generic drivers, your problems, are a driver problem

Comment: @Ramhound i5 4300U, I've been using Thinkpads for many years, this is the way it is, you can only install drivers from Lenovo. It's the same for Surface Pro, you can only install drivers from Microsoft. I don't believe it's a driver issue, I've used this driver version 3958 for 3 months with no problem. This issue begins this week.

Comment: I installed the latest Intel update just the other day on my SP3...looking at the frequnexy your running at the boost frequenxy your suppose to be running at

Comment: @Ramhound Did you installed from windows update or manually from intel? I'm running at 1100 MHz, but only when GPU is idle, if GPU usage is 100%, it automatically decrease to 200 MHz.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't reflect that, downloaded it from intels website

Comment: @Ramhound It's in the graph on the right, clock and load are opposite.